# What happened to most of Five Star Movement (M5S) deputies since the 2018 election?

Tags: parliament, parties, italy

If I'm not mistaken, the Five Star Movement (M5S) [won](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Italian_general_election) 227 seats in lower house in the 2018 election. But they only have [100 now](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Five_Star_Movement&oldid=1105254177). I see that [53 deputies split](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Together_for_the_Future&oldid=1102855004) to De Maio's new party/group (Together for the Future, IpF) this year. But still that leaves 74 more of the original M5S deputies unaccounted for. So what happened to those since the 2018 election?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The parliament

If you want a visual chart of changes, look at the work made by Vittorio Nicoletta showing the Parliament group changes for the [Camera](https://vi-enne.github.io/cambiCamera18/) (lower house) and the [Senato](https://vi-enne.github.io/cambiSenato18/) (high house) with data from Openpolis.

According to the data from Openpolis [Camera](https://parlamento18.openpolis.it/i-gruppi-in-parlamento/camera) and [Senato](https://parlamento18.openpolis.it/i-gruppi-in-parlamento/senato), there have been a total of 259 changes of party by 203 MPs inside this XVIII legislature (2018-2022).

### M5S - 5 Stars Movement

The M5S lost those MPs in favor of other groups:

| Group | Camera | Senato | Tot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Misto | 52 | 15 | 67 |
| Lega | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| FdI | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| IV | 5 | 1 | 6 |
| PD | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| FI | 4 | 2 | 6 |
| LeU | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| IPF | 53 | 11 | 64 |
| CAL-PC-Idv | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| **TOT** | **125** | **46** | **171** |

The summary for M5S is:

|  | Camera | Senato | Tot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Initial MPs | 227 | 112 | 339 |
| Lost MPs | 125 | 46 | 171 |
| Today's MPs | 96 | 62 | 158 |

**n.b.: I did not count those MPs who changed groups and then returned back to M5S.**

---

-- edit --

**Misto group**: in the Italian Parliament, all MPs must be inside a group. The creation of a new group has strict and different rules for each house. The Misto (mixed) group collects two types of MPs:

1. those that do not subscribe to any existing group (e.g.: independent MPs)
2. those whose party does not have the requirements for the creation of a new group.

Comment: What is the "Misto" (mixed?) group, exactly?

Comment: Mkay, seems to be the name of the group of the smaller parties & indepedents https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruppo_misto_nella_XVIII_legislatura And part of that there was apparently a smaller explusion of "Alternativa" some 15 deputies https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pino_Cabras#L'espulsione_dal_M5S_e_la_nascita_di_Alternativa

Comment: In the Italian Parliament, all MPs must be inside a group. The creation of a new group has strict and different rules for each house. The Misto (mixed) group collects two types of MPs: (1) those that do not subscribe to any existing group (e.g.: independent MPs) and (2) those whose party does not have the requirements for the creation of a new group.